# is there a way to get jupyter notebook out of H2O

Tags: h2o

i am building a model using H2O. is there a way H2O can produce Jupyter notebook instead of seeing the predicted model using H2O flow

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, there is no way to produce a jupyter notebook instead.

However, you can write your own jupyter notebook to drive H2O using the python client api.

Here are some references:

http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/algo-params/ntrees.html
http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-py/docs/index.html